# Using NSNumber numberWithBool in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsurl, nsnumber

I submitted my Version 2 of my app for review and it got rejected due to a high backup to iCloud - wasn't aware of this as I only have to pics in my app but anyway. Now I try to convert that code

```
NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *databaseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:databasePath];
    BOOL success = [databaseUrl setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
    if(!success){
    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [databaseUrl lastPathComponent], error);
    }
```

to swift and I couldn't get it work... 
This is what I have so far...

```
func excludeFromBackup() {
    var error:NSError?
    var fileToExclude = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("path")
    var success:Bool = fileToExclude?.setResourceValue(NSNumber.numberWithBool(true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &error)
    if success {
        println("worked")
    } else {
        println("didn't work")
    }
}
```

As you see, I fail with the numberWithBool Value.

Can anyone help me? Did anyone convert it before?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some Swift types (`Int`, `Bool`, `String`, ...) are automatically
bridged to the corresponding Objective-C type, so you can simply write:

```
let success = fileToExclude.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &error)
```

(More details in [Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_42).)

Comment: I tried that one and it didn't work! Why I was down voted? I tested my solution and it worked!

Comment: There is not always one right solution for a problem so there is no reason to down vote if it is not "the one" solution. I might be new here here but I am not a beginner....

Comment: @ArminScheithauer: Your code is correct as well, I just wanted to present a simpler solution. I did not downvote your answer. A possible reason *might be* that you provided no explanation, but I am only speculating.

Comment: Ok then I say sorry and thanks... I didn't thought about an explanation as this is a actually a quite easy function.... Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I got it sorted... Here is the solution.

```
func excludeFromBackup(path:String) {
        var error:NSError?
        var fileToExclude = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)!
        var success:Bool = fileToExclude.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &error)
        if success {
            println("worked")
        } else {
            println("didn't work")
        }
    }
```

That works just fine now.

Thanks anyway...